# Call MVC Service with Forms Authentication from Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authentication

I have ASP.Net Web API service which uses BasicHttpAuthentication. I have another ASP.Net MVC Service which uses Forms Authentication. Both services are using same membership provider and role manager. I want to call MVC service method from Web API method and pass same credentials. Whatever I try, MVC service always returns LoginPage.html.

How can I pass Web API authentificated user credentials to MVC service through forms authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can try solution from here [Mixing MVC forms authentication & web-api basic authentication](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/)